# Application Gateway ARM Template with Private IP Address

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to pass an arm template a static private frontend IP address to create an application gateway? I see that examples in quickstart templates use

```
    "frontendIPConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "appGatewayFrontendIP",
        "properties": {
          "PublicIPAddress": {
           "id": "[variables('appGwPublicIPRef')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
```

For public, but I don't understand the use of "id" here. In the schema example I found this:

```
"properties": {
    "privateIPAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "PrivateIPAddress of the network interface IP Configuration."
    },
    "privateIPAllocationMethod": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Static",
            "Dynamic"
          ]
        },
        {
          "$ref": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#/definitions/expression"
        }
      ],
      "description": "PrivateIP allocation method."
    },
```

But I don't know which types are appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use arm template schema, its garbage. Only use rest api reference. Here's a meaningful example link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/applicationgateways/createorupdate#examples

And here's what you basically need to do:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "properties": {
        "privateIpAddress": "address",
        "privateIpAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "subnet": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vnet', 'subnet'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

I think, only subnet is mandatory.

As for you second question, id is a resourceId of a public Ip address to attach to the Application Gateway.